# How do i take information from a text document and average it in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

For school i'm creating a program in which you input basketball scores, i have it currently add these scores into a text document in the debug folders named simply "Scores.txt", things such as the date, points, rebounds ect. have a ", " in-between each of the values, i intend to have it that i can press a button "btnPPG" that will take a column from the text file to be able to add each individual value and divide it by how many values (averaging) the score, for example the first column holds the dates, and the second the points in that game complementing the date in the second column, I don't have the knowledge to do this as i am fairly new to coding, and can't seem to find some code similar on the internet

Comment: what You try? where is problem, code, ... ?

Comment: What do you mean? Sorry if i said dosen't make sense, i'm still in high school, and as i said i'm fairly new to coding

Comment: Then show us your code so far and tell us: what do you want to do? Unfortunately we can't help you if you have no code.

Comment: Theres **no** columns in a text file... perhaps you could use xml in which you could serialize and deserialize your data into classes in which you can use...

Comment: No it doesn't But what i was saying is in between the scores is "," essentially making columns, im not sure if this will work in VB to just grab the columns

Comment: If data in rows is separated by commas then you have a CSV file, so you should do some reading on how to process such a file in VB. The general steps are: open file, parse data, process data. The processing data part has nothing to do with files because it will be the same for the same data regardless of where that data comes from.  If you need to have numbers to average then you need to learn how to convert the `String` data you read from the file into numbers. Don't look at the whole thing as one problem to solve. Break it into parts and solve each individually, then combine solutions.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Strictly speaking this isn't a code writing or tutorial service, but if you edit your question to include a few lines (say 10) of the text file, maybe we can rustle something together.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think the should work..

The function `ReadTextFromFile`, opens your text file and tries to read it and add each game to a List. Each game should be one item in the List.

The CalculateColumnAverage will iterate through any list passed to it in the correct format and calculate an average of all the values in the column number.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim gamesList As List(Of String())
    Dim ScoreAverage As Single

    Private Sub BtnPPG_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPPG.Click
        gamesList = ReadTextFromFile("c:\Scores.txt")
        'calculate the average of all the numbers in column 3
        'change the number to which ever column is appropriate
        'Don't forget that the first column is 0, the second is 1
        'and so on
        ScoreAverage = CalculateColumnAverage(gamesList, 3)
    End Sub

    Private Function ReadTextFromFile(filePath As String) As List(Of String())
        Dim data As New List(Of String())
        If File.Exists(filePath) Then
            Using MyReader As New FileIO.TextFieldParser(filePath)
                MyReader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
                Dim currentRow As String()
                'Loop through all of the fields in the file. 
                'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing. 
                While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                    Try
                        currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                        data.Add(currentRow)
                    Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                        MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")
                    End Try

                End While
            End Using
        End If
        Return data
    End Function

    Private Function CalculateColumnAverage(dataList As List(Of String()), column As Integer) As Single
        Dim average As Single
        Dim columnTotal As Integer

        For Each game As String() In dataList
            If IsNumeric(game(column)) Then
                columnTotal = columnTotal + game(column)
            Else
                Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException("column", "Column " & column & " does exist")
            End If
        Next
        average = columnTotal / dataList.Count
        Return average
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I'm having the problem where i cant start the program but instead has been replaced with "attached" and i don't know where to go from here.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.